# is there a way to put images on top of each other?

Tags: php, html

I want to know if there is a way in PHP which I could place transparent images on top of each other. The concept goes like this:

- The user gets presented images, which are:
- Background Image, To be placed on the bottom
- Main Character, To Be Placed Directly Behind The Text Stripe
- Frame to be placed around the logo
- Text to be placed on a black stripe, on top of everything.
- The user can select the images he wants to use, just like the preview below.

I don't have a single idea on how to do this since I am still new to PHP.

I have a little preview of what I want: https://sanderc.net/avatar/create.php

edit: Changed the preview link.

Comment: This is more to do with HTML and probably a liberal usage of CSS than PHP

Comment: I see, but I would need a little more explanation on what to exactly do, and the steps I need to take.

Comment: I might suggest you look at the page source of your example

Comment: I can't really tell what is the thing that makes the images go on top of each other. I also don't know how to make a certain image selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something like in the demo. then you need css as well.
some links given below. hope it will be of some help to you.

```
https://www.google.com/search?ei=zSv-XICHJ_WZmgfl_5CQCQ&q=image+on+top+of+another+image+css&oq=image+on+top+of+another+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l2j0i22i30l8.227906.227906..230842...0.0..0.170.170.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.X4ZIg9BRrzg#kpvalbx=1
http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/ontop.html
http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/nFvUu/3/
http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/ontop.html
```

Comment: Thanks, I have gone 50% through, I just need to know how to let the user select the image they want to put as the background, character, and border. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can check
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4jkPGUxXSA
for file upload. just have to display the images in the respective position and css as well